# Distributing a git clone through a filehosting service

Tags: git, gitlab

I've been trying to clone a git repository for a modding project I'm working on. The git repository is 8.5 gigs in size, because the team made the decision to store their binary files in git (I had no part in this decision, but I *do* need every file to work on the project).

The real issue, however, is that the server (located on a different continent) caps my download rate per instance at dial-up speeds. Cloning the entire repository will take over a week.

I have already attempted `git clone --depth=1 -b=master`, to no avail.

**Is it possible to distribute a clone of this repository, perhaps using bundles, through a filehosting service such as Google Drive or Mega.Co.nz?**

Thank you, and my apologies if this is in the wrong section.

Comment: It's definitely *possible*: a bundle is basically just a pack file plus references and `git fetch` simply automates making a pack file with the right references. See the `EXAMPLE` section in the documentation: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html (just replace `master` with `--all` when making the bundle). You will of course have to make and upload the bundle on the "fast" side of your bottleneck link.

Comment: Yeah, now to find someone on my team that with a good upload speed that I can talk into doing this...